# How to remove all inherited CSS styling on a certain page via JS in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, inline-styles

I am working on a site like Codepen and we are trying to get it off the ground.

So, a user can write some code in React and then the site will display what they've written, and will also deploy it. The problem is that some of the elements have styles which are being inherited from the main site, and cannot be overridden via CSS; the only way to do it is via inline styling. Is there some sort of JS code to reset styles to default? Something like

`H1.style.* = "default"`

using `!important` works, but it would be really to be able to give the user a clean slate for CSS when they're coding...

You can see the actual notebook (as we call it) here: https://djit.su/dL22DiUPUmCf2kQMLBoAJ

**As you can see, inline styling works**
[image: Inline Styles work, not from CSS]

**And also using !important works**
[image: !important also works]